# Dynamically Bind UserStore with Ninject

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, ninject, ninject.web.mvc, ninject.web

I have the following user Store:

```
public class UserStoreService<T> : UserStore<T> where T : IdentityUser
{
    public UserStoreService(MainDbContext context)
        : base(context)
    {
    }
}
```

In my Startup, I need to bind this with a custom user from another library. I am trying to avoid to have to reference that library in my project altogether.  I have the interfaces referenced and that is what I am using throughout the whole project to access properties and such.  What I can't figure out is how to dynamically bind the following statement:

```
kernel.Bind<IUserStore<MyCustomUser>>().To<UserStoreService<MyCustomUser>>();
```

`MyCustomUser` extends `IdentityUser`

Answer (score 1):

So there's two ways to achieve bindings without referencing the implementation-assembly directly:

- Create bindings in the implementation assembly
  -- ninject features "Modules" for this, see [here](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject/wiki/Modules-and-the-Kernel). Modules can be loaded, for example, by `kernel.Load(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())`
- Use reflection to find implementation of interfaces and create bindings
  -- ninject has [Ninject.Extensions.Conventions](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Extensions.Conventions) which can simplify things. You'd probably would want to make use of a custom `IBindingGenerator` in your case.
  -- of course you could also roll your own implementation

A word of warning though, many would say that you should employ a composition root and hence you should actually reference the implementation assembly from and create the bindings in the composition root. See [Mark Seemann's argumentation](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/).

Comment: So you are saying that Option 2 is a better approach, using reflection?  I'm having troubles figuring out how to write code that does that.  Would you be able to give me an example? My biggest issue is around the fact that I have to supply a Type (MyCustomUser).  UserStoreService is located in Services dll, where as the MyCustomUser is located in a Models dll.  Neither is being directly referenced in the project, only their contracts (interfaces).

Comment: @Bagzli The [Ninject.Extensions.Conventions Wiki](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Extensions.Conventions/wiki) shows how to use it, plus there's quite a few questions and answers regarding this on Stackoverflow.
My opinion is that a reflection-only approach is kind of brittle, i'd actually prefer Modules - but if you want to write software where you don't depend on the container "too much" then you should write a proper composition root - as described by Mark Seemann.

Comment: Yeah I have gone through all that and I'm still failing to understand how to write that code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you quite understand what interfaces are for. They give you the ability to swap in implementations, but that doesn't mean that you can completely hide the implementation from the application. Everywhere else in your application, you can reference the interfaces, which is good, but in your Ninject config, you have to tell it what it should bind to that interface when it comes across it, which means you application must have a reference to the project where the implementations exist, if only just for this.

Comment: Hi Chris, I believe I have a strong understanding of the use of interfaces.  Yes you are correct on your statement that you have to reference the dll you are using when binding to ninject, BUT you can do so dynamically.  My project will never know about my implementation dll, I will tell ninject via a string the name of my project and it will load an bind everything dynamically.  I already have this working for the simple types.  My problems is when I have classes that impelement Type <T> in them, I'm not sure how to bind those.